# Учебная виртуальная стековая машина с визуальным отладчиком

Tags: отладка, виртуальная-машина, эмулятор

Играюсь с самодельными компиляторами.

Нужен визуальный симулятор стековой машины, можно онлайн, в который можно загрузить ассемблерный код или файл байт-кода, и погонять его в эмуляции пошагово, что-то типа DOSовского TurboDebugger с выводом памяти, стека, точками останова и т.п.

```
.text 
    ptr A
    lit 1.0
    lit 2.3
    mul
    lit 4e-05
    ptr B
    mul
    add
    eq
.data 
.bss 
    A: dw ?
    B: dw ?
.stack
```

Answer (score 1):

1. самостоятельная реализация симулятора (wxPython,C++,..) подходит плохо -- слишком большие затраты времени
2. трансляция в сишный код (одна команда - одна функция) с запуском в любом визуальном отладчике
3. проект nand2tetris:

   http://www.nand2tetris.org/07.php

   http://www.nand2tetris.org/software.php